# 200 Permissions error using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

after get my posts in my web page , then if user login he can add like / comment to that post problem is am getting an error if any user try add like or comment

200  Permissions error

if i login in with my username and password i can make like or add comment !!

am sending like via :

```
jQuery.post('https://graph.facebook.com/'+comm_id+'/likes/',{
                            access_token : "<?php echo $access_token ?>"

                        });
```

CODE :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '',
            'secret' => '',
            'cookie' => true,
        ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {  
    if (session_id()) {

    } else {
        session_start();
    }

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    //check permissions list
    $permissions_list = $facebook->api(
            '/me/permissions', 'GET', array(
        'access_token' => $access_token
            )
    );

    //check if the permissions we need have been allowed by the user
    //if not then redirect them again to facebook's permissions page
    $permissions_needed = array('publish_stream', 'read_stream', 'manage_pages');
    foreach ($permissions_needed as $perm) {
        if (!isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1) {
            $login_url_params = array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages',
                 'fbconnect' =>  1,
        'display'   =>  "page",
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/fb/index.php',
            );
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
            header("Location: {$login_url}");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    //if not, let's redirect to the ALLOW page so we can get access
    //Create a login URL using the Facebook library's getLoginUrl() method
    $login_url_params = array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages',
                'fbconnect' =>  1,
        'display'   =>  "page",
        'redirect_uri'=>'http://localhost/fb/index.php',
    );
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);

    //redirect to the login URL on facebook
    header("Location: {$login_url}");
    exit();
}

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

which access token is for the user is loged in

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `publish_stream` permission for any user you want to be able to create posts for. Remember, creating a comment is still creating content.

Checkout the `publish_stream` permission on [Facebook's permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. This is a superset
>   publishing permission which also includes publish_actions. However,
>   please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.
>   Please read the Platform Policies to ensure you understand how to
>   properly use this permission. Note, you do not need to request the
>   publish_stream permission in order to use the Feed Dialog, the
>   Requests Dialog or the Send Dialog.

Comment: i dont want permission to add post to the user , i need give permission to the user loged in add like to my post , and by the way i already add publish_stream

Comment: You can not like just anything on behalf of the user via the API, without getting the user’s permission to do so first.

Comment: I think you need publish_actions instead
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/

Comment: still getting same error , am sending the request as follow :'https://graph.facebook.com/'+comm_id+'/likes/?access_token = .....  do i miss somthing ?? , i donr know when i loged in with my username and password am allowed to add like to post but other cant!!